# Conflict caused by Tailwind CSS when imported as part of a React NPM package in NextJS app which has tailwind already installed

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js, tailwind-css

I created a custom React NPM package which is built on top of Tailwind CSS and includes it as a DevDependency:

main.css:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

tailwind.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    content: [
      "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    ],
    theme: {
      extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [],
  }
```

postcss.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: {
        tailwindcss: {},
        autoprefixer: {},
    },
};
```

When the package is imported in a nextJS app which has tailwind configured and installed, certain existing components of the nextJS app are not rendered anymore once the NPM package is installed and certain components are called from the package. However, the components coming from the react NPM package are rendered correctly.

Specifically, the sidebar suddenly disappears once components of the package are used on the site. The sidebar consists of components outside of the package but is styled using Tailwind CSS.

Before:
[image]

After:

[image: Screenshot]

Many thanks for any hints!

Comment: Does that mean there are two separate Tailwind css files that are possibly competing for precedence? Or is it all merged? Can you inspect the side bar? Is it not showing due to 
 unexpected styles or some other reason?

Answer (score 3):

Solved the issue by myself. Turns out you need to add `important: true` in tailwind.config.js.

```
module.exports = {
    content: [
        './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
        './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
        './data/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    ],
    theme: {
        extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [],
    important: true,
};
```

Comment: thanks man, solved for me. but im curious how to do this in the package. so we dont need to set `important: true` on each project